# Authentication setup using HTML and Javascript or Angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, rest, authentication

In my project, I implemented CRUD using Asp.net Web API 2 and consumed that using Angularjs. Now I want to build user and admin authentication as two location of the application be authorized to both accordingly. I am already familiar with PHP and ASP.net authentication, but this time I am building my application with HTML and Angularjs only, and I am asked (by a test) to implement user and admin authentication by HTML and Javascript.

1) Please guide me whether to use pure js or angularjs authentication, and what good step by step references. 
2) please explain to me how can I secure two locations of the application, first of for registered users and second is for admins only.

I actually did basic search and got confused, I came here for guidance.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "but this time I am building my application with HTML and Angularjs only" - If the application is built entirely client-side then it cannot be secure whether it's plain JS or AngularJS.

Comment: @tommyd456 So, but what way it can be possible? Considering my backend is Asp.net Web API 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backend: **ASP.Net Web API**
Frontend: **Angular/HTML**

You can create a service endpoint for logging - something like this:

```
public partial class ContainerController
{
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login (string success, string error, string returnUrl)
        {
            //Authenticate User
        }
}
```

Once you've authenticated the user you can redirect the user to a new cshtml page (which is visible only to authenticated users).

Please note that since you're passing your username and id from JavaScript they can be easily detected from a third part intercepting your calls to the server. If you don't want that then you need to run your login page on https. Configuring security certificates and https is a bigger topic and I'll not be able to explain it here.

Comment: No, you do did not understand my concern correctly. My Backend is Asp.net Web API consumed by Angularjs, please update your answer and guide better. Thank you for that.

Comment: Thank you for update. I actually have difficulty understanding creating new methods in addition to the default CRUD methods. The problem is that I am beginner to web api and I face a problem in calling new-created methods (404 error). I am also beginner to routing where I think they use routing although I have read whole articles about that here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions with no benefit fixing my error. However, your post's update defines new api method. So, what should I do?

Comment: So here's the thing - You need to attack the problem in pieces. It seems that you have multiple weak points that you need to address. Try to find answers to following questions:
1. How to set up a basic web api service?
2. How to deploy the service and configure its routing?
3. How to use $http in angular to call web api service endpoint?

Unfortunately, you'll not be able to get all this information here because it's a Q/A forum. Google some and create your own sample app to figure it out.

Comment: Sure, I will do your advice. I really liked your instruction patience and highly respectful manner. Thanks a lot to you Dear @Sidharth Panwar

Comment: You're welcome! Check this article for some insights: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec

Comment: Thank you for that. I actually got understanding to an extend to this article:http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx .. the problem I am solving is that you can access the home page from browser without login. Can you help me solve that limitation? By the way, I already contacted author and nor reply so far.

Comment: Hi Mr. Sidharth Panwar, please upvote I'm in danger of block.